# Image as link doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have `<a>` with background:

```
 <a class="link" href="/#/index"></a>
```

And `css` for it:

```
.link
{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background:  #fff url("/logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Image displays normally, but link doesn't work, when i hover on image cursor is default, not pointer, and page doesn't update after click.

Comment: is the `a` tag lacks class `.home`

Comment: It's working for me here : http://jsfiddle.net/AX53h/ (chrome)

Comment: I tried the fiddle by @RomainBraun in Firefox and IE9 and the link works.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: Why are you putting a logo image in the background instead of an `<img>` tag? Or are you creating a button? In practice, you are missing out on the SEO potential of the `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put `&nbsp;` inside the `a` tag

```
<a class="link" href="/#/index">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The link

```
<a class="link" href="/#/index"></a>
```

But for hover and link you need to display text

```
<a class="link" href="/#/index">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css class refers to `.home` but your link has a class of `link`.

**Edit:**

Just realized that you said the image displays properly (and you've already edited the class in the question).

However I tried your css and link on jsFiddle.net and it worked fine.

**Edit 2:**

Semantically speaking, having an empty link (even one with `&nbsp;`) is bad practice for screen readers and Google.  Since you aren't using an actual image you can't rely on the alt tag, so you should add some descriptive text inside the link and then hide it like so:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="link" href="/#/index">This is my text</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.link
{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background:  #fff url("/logo.png") no-repeat;
  text-align:left;
  text-indent:-999em;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The text indent removes the text to the left while `overflow:hidden` ensures it will never be seen, and that the link clickable area doesn't trail off to the left.

Answer (score 0):

the text / object inside the  tag will only have redirection link use

```
<a><img></a>
```

or

```
<img src="http://asvignesh.in/images/qrcode.png" onClick="window.location.href = 'http://asvignesh.in'" >
```